# Google Cloud Platform "Unspecified" Credential Name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-speech-api

Under ***Google Cloud Platform -> APIs and Services*** I noticed a significant amount of Traffic (Different than "Requests") that I wasn't making. After looking into the traffic it appears to be coming from **"Unspecified"** account credentials. I haven't found anything online or in the documentation about an "Unspecified" account name or what that might mean.

All requests are reporting a 401 http status code so I assume they're not going through...?

It's also worth noting that I disabled the API for a brief (approx 15-45 min) period of time and the traffic shows no "outage" during that time.

- Is this Google doing something?
- Have my credentials have been compromised?
- If they're not going through why are they even showing up?
- Will I be charged for this traffic?

For the time being I plan on leaving the API Enabled seeing as disabling it did nothing anyways.

[Cloud Speech API Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2lbY.png)

---

#### Edit

I reported the issue to Google. This is a known internal issue that is still being worked on. You can view the status of this issue at [issuetracker.google.com](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111450671)

Comment: Hey Buddy, I am going through this error on my cloud firestore api. Can you tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: As far as I know there isn’t really any way to resolve this issue. Just keep an eye on what they charge you. I wish I could give you better advice but this issue has been open since 2018 and Google has done nothing about it. 